# Putting a condition if socket does not get a message

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

I want to perform some tasks if my socket in java does not get any message. But i think that socket.accept() waits until it receives a message.
the following is the code that I have written for the purpose.

```
while (true) {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                message = is.readLine();
                check=0;
                if (message != null) {
                    System.out.println("recieved :" + message);
                    if (message.contains("Dead")) {
                        System.out.println("Player is Dead");

                    else{
                        System.out.println("akakak");
                    }

                }
                else{
          // the code here should run if the socket does not receive any message
                    System.out.println("noeoeo");
                }

            }
```

Comment: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-set-timeout-time-out-java-socket-client

Answer (score 1):

> I think that `socket.accept()` waits until it receives a message.

No. `ServerSocket.accept()` blocks until it receives an inbound *connection*. What you're looking is `Socket.setSoTimeout()` and `SocketTimeoutException`.

```
// The code here should run if the socket does not receive any message
```

No. If `readLine()` returns null the peer has disconnected, and you should do the same. Instead of printing `noeoeo`.